# How to do partial application cache update for list in React-Admin?

Tags: react-admin

I've read blog [React Admin 3.3: Faster Navigation And Reduced Footprint Thanks To Application Cache](https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/03/06/react-admin-3-3.html) but still do not understand know create real cache without need to full update list.
For several list resources which changed rarely I want to cache response in IndexedDb.

Logic for updating and optimistic rendering should be following (if previous version of list already in cache):

1. Each entry in list have timestamp field `last_updated`.
2. When opening list for cached resource my dataprovider return current list version from IndexedDb.
3. Ideally during this loading spinner should continue to rotating (I do not sure if it is possible since I've resolved Promise during previous step)
4. At same time during **step 2** data provider asynchroniously launch fetch new data from API like "Give me new entries updated after **timestampN**, where **timestampN** most newest timestamp in cache.
5. After receiving data from API cache will be updated and data provider should notify react-admin somehow that cached data changed and it need to re-render data table.
6. Finally loading spinner stopped.

Mostly I do not know how to achive **step 5** since it is most important here.

**Can someone help with ideas how to implement such or similar application cache?**